# z and w are two complex numbers prove the relationship

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers such that $|z+w| = |z-w|$

Prove that $\arg z - \arg w = \pm  \ \pi/2$

Can someone please help me?

Comment: $z+w$ and $z-w$ are the diagonals of a certain parallelogram.

Comment: hmm didnt see it that way before

Comment: I guess if u think about it then, then it must make sense, but how do u prove it algebraically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|z+w|^2 = |z|^2+2 \operatorname{re} \overline{z} w + |w|^2$.

$|z-w|^2 = |z|^2-2 \operatorname{re} \overline{z} w + |w|^2$.

If the two are equal, we must have $\operatorname{re} \overline{z} w = 0$.

What does that say about $\operatorname{arg} \overline{z} w$?

Comment: If the number is imaginary?

Comment: This is just the analytic version of Daniel's parallelogram approach.

Comment: sorry can you finish it of please, Im not sure about it still

Comment: If $\operatorname{re} v = 0$, then $v$ is purely imaginary, hence $v = |v| e^{i \theta}$, where $\theta = \pm { \pi \over 2}$.

Comment: There is some awkwardness with $\operatorname{arg}$ which I am avoiding, computations should be performed modulo $2 \pi$. For example, depending on how you compute $\operatorname{arg}$, if you take $z=1, w=-i$, then $\operatorname{arg}z = 0, \operatorname{arg}w = {3 \over 2} \pi$ from which we get $\operatorname{arg}z - \operatorname{arg}w = - {3 \over 2} \pi$. Of course, modulo $2 \pi$ this gives the desired result.