# |z+w| = |z-w| ; prove arg(z) and arg(w) differ by (pi/2)

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm pretty good with complex numbers though I can't figure out how to prove the same.

I experimented with the argand plane a bit yet couldn't come to a solution.

Source: Hasse and Harris IBDP: Application and Interpretation HL

Comment: It's asking to show that a parallelogram with equal diagonals is a rectangle.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/990522/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/573019/42969  – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7Cz%2Bw%7C%20%3D%20%7Cz-w%7C%20%24&p=1)